# Cannot access TYPO3 Backend and Install tool after upgrade from 4.5 to 4.6

Tags: typo3

The server of my provider uses PHP 5.3.11, MySQL 5.1.55. Safe_mode is On. After upgrade source files from 4.5 to 4.6 version, removing cache files, I cannot see Install tool nor Backend. I see only blank page, with source code simple "1". When file ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL is missing I can see only "The Install Tool is locked" message, that's all.

I suppose some settings with PHP are not correctly set. Could you say, which settings I must check, step by step, to get TYPO3 4.6 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install extbase and fluid, if not done yet
2. downgrade to 4.5
3. enable deprecation log (see install tool "enableDeprecationLog")
4. check the logfile in typo3conf/deprecation_*.log
5. try update again
6. use update wizard
7. clear cache
8. check PHP Error if it not working yet

Something in my mind things about downgrade apache to http 1.0 - it can be done via .htaccess. It may happen that you get chunked encoding.

Perhaps deactivate non-system extension?

Comment: 1. I have only "extbase", no "fluid", which extension key do you mean exactly?4. deprecation_*.log is empty, I removed old extensions.

Comment: For 4. deprecation_*.log is empty, I removed old extensions. After your suggestions, it doesn't work :) Simply cannot see anything, so I don't know what to change and it's not my first typo3 installation. Are there any Safe_mode restrictions, they always make problems?

Comment: afair you need to configure safe_mode properly... but it would be easier to just set it off - isnt it deprecated?

Comment: fluid template engine has extension key "fluid". It is a system extension, it should be available within the core.

Comment: Thanx. It seems that I must turn off Safe_mode for higher versions of Typo3 (4.6->)

Comment: Safe mode is useless and does nothing but not saving time for devs.

Comment: Solved. The provider turn off Safe_mode. Now can upgrade to 4.6 and 4.7.